# ValueError with matplotlib.pyplot.bar

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a problem with matplotlib.pyplot.bar, I allready searched for the error but none of the reccomended solutions have worked for me. I am trying to code a programm (as a homework assignement), that will let me count the number of occurences of each letter in a newspaper article and plot their relative frequency(relative to the number of all letters used) for two years side by side, which works fine up until I try to plot it. Then I get this error:

```
ValueError: incompatible sizes: argument 'height' must be length 26 or scalar
```

the function that is throwing the error is:

```
def tazBarPlots(relFreq2015, relFreq2018):
    N = len(relFreq2015)
    ind = np.arange(N)
    width=0.1
    relFreq5=np.asarray(relFreq2015)
    relFreq8=np.asarray(relFreq2018)
    print len(relFreq5), len(relFreq8)
    p = plt.subplot()
    rects2015 = p.bar(ind, width, relFreq5, color='red')
    rects2018 = p.bar(ind + width, width, relFreq8, color='blue')
    plt.show()
```

relFreq2015 and relFreq2018 are both lists of float numbers with length 26, which contain the relative frequencies of every letter of the alphabet as an average over 20 articles (2015) and 19 (2018). Anyone got any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Got height and width backwards?

Comment: yeah that was the problem... just had to change width with relFreq5 and relFreq8